# Action Script 3.0 - MouseEvent Listener + function issues

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, mouseevent

I'm working on a project that has multiple clickable objects on the stage.

However, when I create the following function, I getting the last defined eventlistener .

```
// Event listeners
antwoordBox1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, antwoordboxclick);
antwoordBox2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, antwoordboxclick);

function antwoordboxclick(event:MouseEvent):void {

    trace (event.currentTarget.name); // traces 'antwoordBox2' , whether I click any of the buttons.

    if (event.currentTarget.name == 'antwoordBox1') {

         trace('antwoordBox1 selected');

    }

    if (event.currentTarget.name == 'antwoordBox2')  {

        trace('antwoordBox2 selected');
    }

    currentQuestion++; // function to handle after above

    trekNieuweVraag(); // another function to handle after above
}
// end of my code
```

Whatever I try, I don't get it fixed. When I use event.target , I get the child movieclip name inside antwoordBox2 (or antwoordBox1) .

Hope anyone can help me! :)

Comment: Try to verify if your `antwoordBox2` is not over `antwoordBox1`.

Comment: subdan's solution works @akmozo, many thanks for thinking with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Disable mouse interaction with children of antwoordBox's:

   ```
   antwoordBox1.mouseChildren = false;
   antwoordBox2.mouseChildren = false;
   ```
2. Register event listener:

   ```
   addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, antwoordboxclick);
   ```
3. Inside the event handler:

   ```
   if (event.target == antwoordBox1)
       trace('antwoordBox1 selected');
   else if (event.target == antwoordBox2)
       trace('antwoordBox2 selected');
   ```

Comment: Many thanks for helping me out @subdan. You are the bomb! ;-) I was looking for the mouseChildren solution. Thanks!